# How were the views in youtube were managed?

Tags: android, layout, youtube

I wondered if there is more to it, but how was made the build of the application so that the video will be on top of the search screen behind it,was it simply a 
Framelayout that was uses with multiple views inside it and manipulation of the video player container's size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can inspect the View hierarchy of any application using DDMS.
I just tried to figure out Youtube's hierachy and found it to be very complex. Basically the video is a self contained FrameLayout, and the rest of the content is another FrameLayout. This allows the video to keep playing in the corner while you search for stuff.

Here's a simplified version of the hierachy:

```
<Parent>
  <FrameLayout>
    Video info AND search functionality
  </FrameLayout>
  <FrameLayout>
    The video
  </FrameLayout>
</Parent>
```

There's bound to be a lot of magic behind the scenes, of course.

Comment: and what about the parent view that holds both of them?,and i guess it is a complex code of view animation that changes the video size and and pops up or down the comments depends on the user's finger scroll input?

Comment: The hierarchy inspector produced extremely nested structure with those two layouts inside, but the main magic happens at that level. When the video is about to be minimized, the content of the first framelayout changes (or rather one of it's children becomes visible and the other invisible) to show the search view and hide the video description. The animation itself might not be that complex, but the way it manages the description/search view switch probably is.